# Simplest nested block parser

Tags: lexer

I want to write a **simple** parser for a nested block syntax, just hierarchical plain-text. For example:

```
Some regular text.
This is outputted as-is, foo{but THIS
is inside a foo block}.

bar{
  Blocks can be multi-line
  and baz{nested}
}
```

What's the simplest way to do this? I've already written 2 working implementations, but they are overly complex. I tried full-text regex matching, and streaming char-by-char analysis.

I have to teach the workings of it to people, so simplicity is paramount. I don't want to introduce a dependency on Lex/Yacc Flex/Bison (or PEGjs/Jison, actually, this is javascript).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good choices probably boil down as follows:

- Given your constaints, it's going to be recursive-descent. That's a fine way to go even without constraints.
- you can either parse char-by-char (traditional) or write a lexical layer that uses the local string library to scan for `{` and `}`. Either way, you might want to return three terminal symbols plus EOF: BLOCK_OF_TEXT, LEFT_BRACE, and RIGHT_BRACE.

Comment: Yeah, I went for recursive descent. It may take some explaining to lay down the concept, but after that, the code is very readable and the flow is self-evident.

Answer (score 1):

```
   char c; 

   boolean ParseNestedBlocks(InputStream i)
      {  if ParseStreamContent(i)
         then {  if c=="}" then return false
                            else return true
              }
         else return false;

   boolean ParseSteamContent(InputStream i)
    {  loop:
         c = GetCharacter(i);
         if c =="}" then return true;
         if c== EOF then return true;
         if c=="{"
             {  if ParseStreamContent(i)
                  {  if c!="}" return false; }
                else return false;
             }
         goto loop
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Recently, I've been using parser combinators for some projects in pure Javascript.  I pulled out the code into a separate project; [you can find it here](https://github.com/mattfenwick/UnParse-js).  This approach is similar to the recursive descent parsers that @DigitalRoss suggested, but with a more clear split between code that's specific to your parser and general parser-bookkeeping code.

A parser for your needs (if I understood your requirements correctly) would look something like this:

```
var open  = literal("{"),                 // matches only '{'
    close = literal("}"),                 // matches only '}'
    normalChar = not1(alt(open, close));  // matches any char but '{' and '}'

var form = new Parser(function() {}); // forward declaration for mutual recursion

var block = node('block',
                 ['open',  open       ],
                 ['body',  many0(form)],
                 ['close', close      ]);

form.parse = alt(normalChar, block).parse; // set 'form' to its actual value

var parser = many0(form);
```

and you'd use it like this:

```
// assuming 'parser' is the parser
var parseResult = parser.parse("abc{def{ghi{}oop}javascript}is great");
```

The parse result is a syntax tree.

In addition to backtracking, the library also helps you produce nice error messages and threads user state between parser calls.  The latter two I've found very useful for generating brace error messages, reporting both the problem and the location of the offending brace tokens when: 1) there's an open brace but no close; 2) there's mismatched brace types -- i.e. `(...]` or `{...)`; 3) a close brace without a matching open.

Comment: This is a very beautiful abstraction! Why don't you give it some extra doc work and make it into a library?

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn thanks!  Finally got around to cleaning it up a bit.